# Inputting/Accessing data for GUI MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, import, matlab-figure

I wish to plot a simple graph of my data with sliders to change the coefficient of the y-axis data. I have created my GUI interface from quick start, with plot and sliders. I now wish to write the code (I believe in the `simpleguide_OpeningFcn` section) to import my data sets. My data sets are 5 different `300x1` vectors which I currently import into a a normal MATLAB file using an import function named `importfile2.m`.

Any help on how to get this data into the GUI for my simple `plot(x,y)` would be much appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to use [setappdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html?refresh=true) and [getappdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html) to fetch the data wherever you want from your GUI.

For example, at t he end of your `importfile2.m` you could use setappdata to store the data in some variable. The first argument tells MATLAB in what workspace to save it. You could, for example, use the GUI interface in itself or use the base workspace, accessible from everywhere. That's the most general way:

```
setappdata(0,'FancyName',YourData); %// The 0 is for the base workspace,i.e. the 'root'.
%//YourData is the actual data and 'FancyName' is whatever name you give them. It does not have to be the same name as the variable in your function. The important thing is to use the same name in getappdata as below.
```

If you wanted to associate the data only with the GUI figure, you would use something like this:

```
setappdata(handles.YourFigure_Tag,'FancyName',YourData);
```

To get the data in the GUI, use getappdata in its opening function (or in any callback you want) and you're good to go:

```
Data_inGUI = getappdata(0,'FancyName'):
```

A more robust way would be to store directly the data in the handles structure of the GUI, so that it's accessible from every callback:

```
handles.Data_inGUI = getappdata(0,'FancyName'):
guidata(hObject,handles); %// Update handles structure; important!
```

And that should do it. Hope that helps!

**EDIT** I think another solution would be to save a `.mat` file at the end of the import function and load it in the OpeningFcn of the GUI. Than might be simpler/faster.

**EDIT 2** Following your comment below, here is what I would do:

1) In the OpeningFcn of the GUI, import the data.

```
[Date,OutAirTemp,SupAirtemp] = importfile3('AHU7Oct.csv')
```

Then you can store everything in the handles structure:

```
handles.Data = Date;
handles.OutAirTemp = OutAirTemp;
handles.SupAirtemp = SupAirtemp;
guidata(hObject,handles); %// Update handles structure.
```

Then elsewhere in the GUI (i.e. other callbacks) you can fetch the data as regular, i.e. using for example:

```
NewDate = handles.Date - 4 %// or whatever.
```

Is it a bit clearer?

Comment: Thank you. I shall have to have a proper look at this on Monday in order to accept as answer though. Cheers

Comment: Hi @josh so did you get a chance to try the code above?

Comment: Hi @Benoit_11 . Sorry I have not written back sooner. I have been trying to implement it but have been struggling. I do not really understand how GUI's, callback and handles work so I have been trying to get my head around this. so far I have:
`[Date,OutAirTemp,SupAirtemp] = importfile3('AHU7Oct.csv')`

after this step do I use:
`handles.Data_inGUI = getappdata(0,'OutAirTemp');` or `handles.Data_inGUI = getappdata(0,'AllData');` for `AllData = [Date,OutAirTemp,SupAirtemp]`

Comment: I would go with the 2nd option, using 'AllData'. Then you should be able to fetch each data (Date, OutAirTemp,SupAirtemp) individually. Please see my edited answer I'll try to make it clearer.

Comment: It makes a bit more sense and does work. However, I don't see what `guidata(hObject,handles);` actually does. Is it possible to give me a brief overview? Many thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: You're welcome! guidata is actually used whenever you make a change to the data store in the handles structure, so it's used to update it between callbacks. You might want to look at this link for more info, that should make thing clearer. Glad to help! http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html

Comment: Thanks. I have read that page but your one sentence clears it up more than that page. I often find these Mathworks docs have too much jargon for me to understand it. Cheers.

Comment: haha yep I agree with you they don't always make things clear. Cheers!

Comment: Oh I saw your new question about sliders; I forgot to mention that you can use guidata(...) once at the end of callbacks, since while inside a callback MATLAB is aware that variables have changed so there is no need to update it each time a variable is changed; only once at the end.

Comment: Many thanks. I shall see if this change helps with my sliders problem.